# Creating an expression tree for string-concatinating two objects

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

I'm just learning about `Expression` and their expression-trees to use them with IronPython (but that's irrelevant for now).

What I'm trying to do is, creating an expression tree like the following lambda:

```
Func<T, int, string> func = (s,t) => s + t;
```

My current function is this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, int, string>> StringConcatSelector<T>()
{
    var parameterParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var paramToString = typeof(T).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Name=="ToString");
    var parameter = Expression.Call(parameterParam, paramToString);


    var intParameterParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "s");
    var intParameterToString = typeof(int).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "ToString");
    var intParameter = Expression.Call(intParameterParam, intParameterToString);

    var stringConcat = typeof(string).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Concat");

    var result = Expression.Call(stringConcat, parameter, intParameter);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int, string>>
                         (result, parameterParam, intParameterParam);
}
```

the `Expression.Call`of `String.Concat` won't work this way, because of invalid parameter-count. 
So I think I need something like:

- create a `List<string>`-variable-expression
- add both values to the list
- use `String.Concat`with the list-expression.

Am I right?

If yes, how can I create a List-variable (or an Array), add both values to take it as parameter for my `String.Concat`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String.Concat` method has 11 (!) overloads, and you are taking a random one.

The most appropriate for your case is

```
public static String Concat(String str0, String str1)
```

which you can get by using the following `Type.GetMethod` overload

```
public MethodInfo GetMethod(string name, Type[] types)
```

where the `types` array represents the type of the method arguments:

```
var stringConcat = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat",
    new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
```

Comment: Oh. Yes. I've been headless to this. Great, it works perfectly :)

Comment: Alternatively you could use `new [] {typeof(object), typeof(object)}` to call the overload that takes two `object` arguments, and remove the need to call `ToString()`. With the interpreted expression compiler that'd also likely be a bit more efficient as there's fewer steps for the interpreter. WIth the IL-compiling one it'd likely be slightly less efficient (`int.ToString()` doesn't have to box when called directly, but this would box) but the simplifying of the expression is probably still worth it.

Comment: @JonHanna thanks for your hint, but now I'm getting an exception. It can't use an object from type Int32 as a parameter from type Object.

Comment: @JonHanna This is indeed an alternative, but then you have to wrap the arguments in `Expression.Convert(expr, typeof(object))`

Comment: @IvanStoev yep, that works. What would be more efficient in your opinion? I mean, when I override `ToString` I'll get my string - I won't get it, when I'm casting to object. would I? Or does string-concat call `ToString`?

Comment: IMO the string version is better, but as Jon said, it depends on context . The `ToString` call can be simplified by using `Expression.Call(expr, "ToString", Type.EmptyTypes)`

Comment: @IvanStoev Okay. So I will check, what will be working better with IronPython :) thanks for your help & answers!

Comment: I'd probably go with whichever version I found more convenient until it proved to be a hot-spot, and if I did find it to be in a hot-spot I'd measure to be sure, though I'd expect the object version to be a bit more performant in a UWP context, and the string version to be a bit more in other contexts (UWP compiles expressions differently).